# Which is better: overloading operator* or overloading cast operator?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading

I have two classes, Permutation and Cycle. A cycle is essentially a special kind of permutation, but it's not a derived class of Permutation, partially for the following reason. The product of two permutations is another permutation whereas the product of cycles is generally not another cycle. The product of a cycle and a permutation is a permutation.

For permutations p1, p2 and cycles c1, c2, I hope that the intended meaning of the following statements should is clear:

```
Permutation p3 = p1*p2;
Permutation p4 = p1*c1;
Permutation p5 = c1*p1; 
Permutation p6 = c1*c2;
```

The basic structure of my Cycle and Permutation classes is as follows:

```
class Cycle
{
public:
   // stuff ...     
};

class Permutation
{
public:
    Permutation(const Cycle& cycle);

    friend
    Permutation operator*(const Permutation& left, const Permutation& right);
    // stuff ...
};
```

How can/should I add code (or change code) so as to realize the intended usage above?

I have a few (possibly flawed) ideas:

The first idea to modify the Permutation class like this:

```
class Permutation
{
    friend Permutation operator*(const Permutation&, const Cycle&);
    friend Permutation operator*(const Cycle&, const Permutation&);
    friend Permutation operator*(const Cycle&, const Cycle&);

public:
    Permutation(const Cycle& cycle);

    friend
    Permutation operator*(const Permutation& left, const Permutation& right);
    // stuff ...
};
```

I think this would work, but I thought that this might be a good situation for supplying a conversion operator.

Here is my second idea:

```
class Permutation
{

public:
    Permutation(const Cycle& cycle);

    friend
    Permutation operator*(const Permutation& left, const Permutation& right);
    // stuff ...
};

class Cycle
{
public:
    operator Permutation() const
    {
        Permutation p(*this);
        return p;
    }
    // stuff ...     
};
```

I think that this second idea should work for:

```
Permutation p4 = p1*c1;
```

but not:

```
Permutation p5 = c1*p1; 
Permutation p6 = c1*c2;
```

Here is a third idea:

```
class Permutation
{
    friend Permutation operator*(const Permutation&, const Permutation&);

public:
    Permutation(const Cycle& cycle);

    //friend
    //Permutation operator*(const Permutation& left, const Permutation& right);
    // stuff ...
};

class Cycle
{
public:
    operator Permutation() const
    {
        Permutation p(*this);
        return p;
    }
    // stuff ...     
};
```

I suspect that this might work for

```
Permutation p4 = p1*c1;
Permutation p5 = c1*p1;
```

but I can't imagine that the compiler would know to type convert both arguments in the assignment:

```
Permutation p6 = c1*c2;
```

Thanks in advance for your comments and suggestions.

Dan

Comment: Re "how can/should I add code (or change code) so as to realize the intended usage above?", why do you think you have to do *anything* extra? Anyway, please do post real code when you try to communicate what your real code is. I fixed the lacking `friend` keywords but there may be other problems left that needlessly may confuse.

Comment: Voting to close as lacking reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is not do Cycle derived from Permutation. This is my suggestion:

```
class Permutation
{
public:
    virtual bool IsCycle()
    {
        return false;
    }

    virtual Permutation& operator*(Permutation& right);
};

class Cycle: public Permutation
{
public:
    virtual bool IsCycle()
    {
        return true;
    }

    Permutation& operator*(Permutation& right);
};

Permutation& Permutation::operator*(Permutation& right)
{
    // in this case left operand is NOT a Cycle
    // right operand could be anything

    Permutation& p1 = *this;

    if(right.IsCycle())
    {
        Cycle& c1 = *dynamic_cast<Cycle*>(&right);
        // code for case Permutation p4 = p1*c1;
    }
    else
    {
        Permutation &p2 = right;
        // code for Permutation p3 = p1*p2;
    }
}

Permutation& Cycle::operator*(Permutation& right)
{
    // in this case left operand IS a Cycle
    // right operand could be anything
    Cycle& p1 = *this;
    if(right.IsCycle())
    {
        Cycle& c2 = *dynamic_cast<Cycle*>(&right);
        // code for case Permutation p6 = c1*c2;
    }
    else
    {
        Permutation &p1 = right;
        // code for Permutation p5 = c1*p1; 
    }
}
```